# How to make image circe in Raphael js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, raphael

I am passing image to Raphael. Currently image is displaying square, i want the image to displayed in circle format.

```
<div class="demo"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
var r = Raphael("demo")

var myimage="xyz.jpg"

var img = r.image(myimage, 81, 80, 50, 50); 
   // displaying image in square (need to be circle)
```

Please help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function Element.attr(…), sets the attributes of an element. Perhaps you can create a circle and then fill it with your image. The attr is "fill".

```
var circle = paper.circle(50, 40, 10);
// Sets the fill attribute of the circle to red (#f00)
circle.attr("fill", "#f00");
```

That example is from the Raphael's web, you should try:

```
circle.attr("fill", myimage);
```

or

```
circle.attr("fill", "xyz.jpg");
```

Hope that helps,
Gabriel.

Comment: Thanks!! It works. But image is completely zoomed inside the circle. Any idea how get complete image inside the circle. Thanks once again

Comment: I'm glad to hear it :), for the zooming problem, you can try the width and height attributes, check this API guide: http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.image.

Answer (score 1):

You need to draw a circle and then fill it with an image.  This has already been answered [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976838/raphael-drawing-circle-with-two-sectors-from-different-images)